# Class not found

Tags: php, mysql

This is the error I am getting.

> Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in C:\wamp\www\midtermexam\read.php on line 11

```
<?php
    include 'database.php';
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }

    if ( null==$id ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        $pdo = Database::connect(); //HERE IS THE LINE PROBLEM
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students where id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        Database::disconnect();
    }
?>
```

And here is my database file database.php

```
<?php 
   $DB_HOST = 'localhost'; 
   $DB_USER = 'root'; 
   $DB_PASS = '';
   $DB_NAME = 'midtermexam'; 
   try{ 
       $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};
       dbname={$DB_NAME}",$DB_USER,$DB_P‌​ASS); 
       $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
  } 
  catch(PDOException $e){
       echo $e->getMessage(); 
  } ?>
```

Comment: Whats the problem here? It's says that the class 'Database" cant be found. Do you have the php-file "database.php"? Do you have the class 'Database'? Is the path correct?

Comment: I assume the class Database is defined within 'database.php' ?  Can you include the contents of that file in your question?  As a guess I'd say possibly a namespace issue, but without seeing what is in database.php it's mostly guessing

Comment: Going to need more information(code) here... what is inside of `database.php`. Is the class actually `Database` and not `database` _(wild guess based on capitalization differences of included file and class name)_

Comment: HERE IS THE database.php                                                                                  

<?php

 $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
 $DB_USER = 'root';
 $DB_PASS = '';
 $DB_NAME = 'midtermexam';
 
 try{
  $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);
  $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 }
 catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
 }
 
?>

Comment: in database.php you don't define the Database class... is it defined somewhere else? from the looks of it you already establish a DB connection in database.php so you could remove the line `$pdo = Database::connect();` $DB_con should hold your connection

Comment: @sietse85 if i remove that new error will appear

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have not tested it but it should be fairly close.

```
 <?php 
# database.php
#############################
$DB_HOST = 'localhost'; 
$DB_USER = 'root'; 
$DB_PASS = ''; 
$DB_NAME = 'midtermexam'; 
try
{ 
    $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST}; dbname={$DB_NAME}",$DB_USER,$DB_P‌​ASS); 
    $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
} 
catch(PDOException $e)
{ 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
} 

#############################
?>

<?php
# read.php
#############################
$id = null;
if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}

if ( null==$id )
{
  header("Location: index.php");
} 
else 
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students where id = ?";
  $q = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute(array($id));
  $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

#############################
?>
```

From what I can tell you are using the name of the database file as the class name, however, you have created the instance of the database connection as $DB_con within the database.php file.

This may help a little for further reading.
[Sitepoint PDO](https://www.sitepoint.com/re-introducing-pdo-the-right-way-to-access-databases-in-php/)

If you get any issues with this give us a shout.

Good Luck,

Blinky

Comment: error occurs...  
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: DB_con in C:\wamp\www\midtermexam\read.php on line 14
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0007 246376 {main}( ) ..\read.php:0

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\midtermexam\read.php on line 14
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0007 246376 {main}( ) ..\read.php:0

Comment: Try placing the contents of the database.php into the read.php and commenting out the include, see if that works?

Answer (score -2):

step 1：
     check your database configuation in database.php, make sure that all necessary params have been set and all the values are correct.

step 2： 
  if step 1 can not solve your problem, make sure your database server is running, your network is alive.

that's my view, hope it's useful for you.

Comment: here is the database.php code

<?php

 $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
 $DB_USER = 'root';
 $DB_PASS = '';
 $DB_NAME = 'midtermexam';
 
 try{
  $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);
  $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 }
 catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
 }
 
?>